# How to differentiate between static global variable and extern global variable with same name?

Tags: c

I have 2 files:

```
file1.c:
static int k = 3;

file2.c
int k = 5
```

Is there any way to access the extern variable k inside file2.c?

Comment: You can anyway access the variable k in file2.c. Do you mean how to access the static int k inside file2.c? it is not allowed. It is 'static'.

Comment: I meant the other way round. int k inside file1.c

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible. : (

Comment: The sole purpose of declaring a file scope variable static, as in file1.c, is to prevent other files from accessing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. You should rename either one of your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Any variable is declared as a static variable, it can be accessed only with in a file or function. even if you declare extern int k also it cannot be accessed.